# Error in double maximum number calculation program in java

Tags: java

I have written the program in java and the program is supposed to find maximum number of type double, eclipse shows me some error. Following is the code

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MaxDouble {
         public static void main (String[]  args){
          Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
          
          System.out.println ("Enter the three double numbers separated by spaces");
          
          double d1 = inp.nextDouble();
          double d2 = inp.nextDouble();
          double d3 = inp.nextDouble();
          double result = maximum (d1, d2, d3);
          
          System.out.println ("Maximum is"+ result);
          
          public static double maximum (double x, double y, double z)
          {
           double maxValue = x;
           if (y > maxValue)
            maxValue = y;
           if (z > maxValue)
            maxValue = z;
           
           return maxValue;
          }
         }
 
}
```

Comment: You might want to include your program in this question

Comment: I have added it. New user on Stackoverflow, it will take me bits of time to get used to it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I think @Eran made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your `maximum` method outside your `main` method.

```
public class MaxDouble 
{
    public static void main (String[]  args)
    {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println ("Enter the three double numbers separated by spaces");       
        double d1 = inp.nextDouble();
        double d2 = inp.nextDouble();
        double d3 = inp.nextDouble();
        double result = maximum (d1, d2, d3);

        System.out.println ("Maximum is"+ result);               
    }

    public static double maximum (double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double maxValue = x;
        if (y > maxValue)
            maxValue = y;
        if (z > maxValue)
            maxValue = z;

        return maxValue;
    }       
}
```